# Not able create build using sonarqube and gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-web

Facing below error while trying sonarqube plugin with gradle :

```
Is 

plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.2"
}


working perfectly ? 

I am getting following error


Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.sonarqube', version: '2.2']
> Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/2.11/plugin/use/org.sonar
qube/2.2'.
   > This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that
 the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server
```

When I tried to hit the url directly in browser  :

```
https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/2.11/plugin/use/org.sonar%20qube/2.2.1

it's giving following output :
```

{
  "message" : "no 'org.sonar qube' plugin available - see https://plugins.gradle.org for available plugins",
  "errorCode" : "UNKNOWN_PLUGIN"
}

Is everything okay for gradle plugin ?

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: @tddmonkey Thanks for response. Not sure what's wrong with my code.

Comment: @tddmonkey can you help me with what response the following url is giving to you please ?                                                                                            https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/2.11/plugin/use/org.sonarqube/2.2

Comment: That endpoint works fine for me.  This sounds like it might be a problem on your end

Comment: sure @tddmonkey I ll check it from my end. Thanks for response again.

Comment: @tddmonkey :  can you please help me with how can I provide required lib to gradle plugin for below error  :
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.sonarsource.scanner.api:sonar-scanner-api:2.8.
     Required by:
         :Sources:unspecified > org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-
plugin:2.2
      > Could not resolve org.sonarsource.scanner.api:sonar-scanner-api:2.8.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/sonarsource/s
canner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.8/sonar-scanner-api-2.8.pom'.